# Provide limited API externally as DLL

Tags: c#, dll

If you had to expose functionality externally as a DLL but only a subset of functionality (meaning you can't provide a core DLL as it would expose everything) how is best to do this?

At the moment I can't really see any way of doing it that doesn't involve recreating the parts of the core library in a seperate DLL.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `internal` along with Friend Assemblies. Your API can be a friend of the core library allowing access to internal members.

See here for more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.90).aspx

This would allow you to keep your core objects internalised whilst allowing the API access to them.

Note that you will STILL need to supply the core library. There's no way around this unless you use something to merge the .NET assemblies or you compile the code into your API library.

However I think this is a bad idea and you should keep such entities separate. I don't see why there is an issue shipping more than one library thesedays.

FYI - ILMerge will let you merge .NET assemblies, you can get it from here - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: Does this require the original core library to have been built with this in mind?

Comment: The issue surrounds more if someone took the core dll and decompiled it. I suppose it will just need to be a copy of the functionality that we're providing.

Comment: They can take your final library and decompile that too. So it's a moot point :)

Comment: Yes but we can live with them decompiling the limited functionality we want to provide, but if they could decompile the full library then that's another matter. A more granular codebase would probably be a better solution I guess.

Comment: You're still providing both sets of code in one form or another (you have to), so either way if they want to they can get at the non-limited code through Reflection/ildasm etc. The only surefire way is to non distribute the code. You can't avoid this sadly. You can mitigate it by obfuscating core (but the API library will still be able to call into core).

Comment: This is what I mean though, we'll basically have to create a 3rd dll with a copy of the code that we want to distribute and containing nothing that don't want to distribute. Effectively meaning we'll have duplicate code :s Not sure how I feel about that.

Comment: Yeh you'll need to extract the `common` code so that it can be shared by both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Surely by just creating a new project that wraps the core DLL, exposing only the methods you want exposed, each of which is acting more or less as a "pass-through" to the "Same" method in the core?

So if you core is called `Core` :)
it might have:

```
public int Foo()
{
    //blah
}

public int Bar()
{
    /blah
}
```

and if you want to only expose `Foo`, then you create a new project which references `Core`, and looks like this:

```
using Core;

public class MyApi
{
    private Core _coreInstance.... //some way of reaching Core, in other words

    public int Foo()
    {
        return _coreInstance.Foo();
    }
}
```

An advantage of creating a separate assembly here is that you are then treating your core functionality as one concept, and the exposure of it publicly (*to a particular purpose or audience*) as another. You may very well want to expose "publicly" different functionality at a later stage, *but to a different audience* - you now have 2 different public APIs required: therefore any notion of what was "public" in your core assembly is now potentially ambiguous.

Comment: This would require you to include the core DLL in the files you pass across or .Net would throw a not found exception.

Comment: so is your concern more about the external distribution of your core DLL that could then be used directly?

Comment: Yes, basically we need to provide a subset of functionality externally without exposing any core mechanisms. Even if we could somehow "merge" the core dll into a wrapper it could still be decompiled.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the aims you follow in hiding the core libraries.

If you don't want to allow your customers to call the code, for example if that may break usage scenarios of your libraries, or may cause undesirable behavior, or whatever to prevent CALLING the code, you can make the protected classes internal, and use InternalsVisibleToAttribute to include the Facade assembly. I would even use one more build configuration if I still needed core classes to be visible in my applications:

```
#if PUBLIC_BUILD
    internal 
#else
    public
#endif
    class ProtectedCoreClass
```

But of course if you have too many classes, some script should be prepared to change the existing classes, and Visual Studio's new class template should be modified.

But another case is if you want to prevent the source code from being WATCHED by your customers in order to hide some super unique algorithms or something. Then you should look into some code obfuscator. But there is absolutely no way to 100% guarantee the code from being decompiled and analyzed. It's only about the price crackers or competitors pay for it.

But if HIDING the source code is still extremly important, you should probably just host your code on your servers (to make sure the code is physically inaccessible) or in the cloud, and provide a WCF or a web service your exposing assembly will call.